# How to add localStorage to my multilanguage website / Jquery / JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies, local-storage

**Hello,**

I've written a multilanguage website using jquery. The translator works perfect. There are no bugs but whenever i refresh the browser or click the link, the page returns to it's original form.

This code is from YouTube tutorial but there is no explanation how to add Cookies or localStorage to it. This is the first time I will be doing it and this is just too hard for me to figure out on my own.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arrLang = {
      'pl': {
        'home': 'Strona główna',
        'about': 'O nas',
        'contact': 'Kontakt',
        'gallery': 'Galeria',
        'callnow': 'Zadzwoń teraz i umów przeprowadzkę!'
      },
      'en': {
        'home': 'Home',
        'about': 'About',
        'contact': 'Contact',
        'gallery': 'Gallery',
        'callnow': 'Call now and sign up!'
      }
    };

    $(function() {
      $('.translate').click(function() {
        var lang = $(this).attr('id');

        $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
          $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
        });
      });
    });
</script>




<button id="pl" class="translate">Polski</button>
<button id="en" class="translate">English</button>
<nav class="header-bottom-left">
    <ul>
        <a href="index.php#indexmain"><li class="lang" key="home">Strona główna</li></a>
        <a href="about.php#indexabout"><li class="lang" key="about">O nas</li></a>
        <a href="gallery.php#indexgallery"><li class="lang" key="gallery">Galeria</li></a>
        <a href="contact.php#indexcontact"><li class="lang" key="contact">Kontakt</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Can u please help me add a localStorage or Cookies to this code? The desing of this translation is just great for me cause it's not interrupting the URL of the site.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.check stored language in local storage first
2.save clicked button language in local storage
Tried to explain how in comments

```
function translateLang(lang)
    {
        $('.lang').each(function(index, item) {
          $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
        });
    }

    $(function() {
        //first check for stored language in localStorage i.e. fetch data from localStorage
        let stored_lang = localStorage.getItem("stored_lang");
        //if any then translate page accordingly
        if(stored_lang != null && stored_lang != undefined)
        {
            lang = stored_lang;
            translateLang(lang);
        }


      $('.translate').click(function() {
        var lang = $(this).attr('id');
         //on click store language to localStorage
        localStorage.setItem("stored_lang",lang);
        translateLang(lang);
      });

    });
```

You can Play around [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/eh9m50wt/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't completely understand this but It works just great :) Weird thing is that when I removed my buttons from one div to another and refresh the site, the browser started to throw "undefined properties in jQuery" error. When I deleted the cookie manually it worked fine again.